# Rails Admin integration with Mobility gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, mobility

I'm trying to use the Mobility gem with Rails Admin.
I am able to edit fields through the Rails Admin interface (like the impact_description of a Ngo model) and it correctly changes the translation tables:

[image: testing on rails console if it changed the impact description]

But the problem is, the Rails Admin interface does not show the correct translation (it is showing in pt-BR, even when the app is in english):

[image]

Has anyone sucessfully integrated Rails Admin with the Mobility gem? Thanks for the attention

EDIT:
In my `rails_admin.rb` (initializer) I have the regular configurations for all actions (only changing new):

```
config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new do
      except [RewardRule, SuggestedFeed]
    end
    export
    import
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    # delete
    clone
    show_in_app

    ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
    # history_index
    # history_show
  end
```

And for the Ngo model I don't have any custom configuration, only that it is included on the Rails Admin models:

```
# rails_admin.rb
config.included_models = [..., Ngo, ...]
```

Comment: Are you changing the I18n.locale?

Comment: Yes, I was able to change I18n locale, it even updates the correct mobility translation table.
The only thing not working is the "show" of the field. It correctly updates the english and portuguese tables, and I can correctly fetch does data too. Only in the "show" of Rails Admin it is not showing

Comment: Can you include the code that configures the “show” action please?

Comment: added my rails_admin initializer config. I did not actually change the default configs

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to do it after some research in the Rails Admin api.
For this to work on the Ngo model in the show action, for example, I did:

```
config.model Ngo do
  show do
    fields do
      formatted_value{ bindings[:object].send(method_name) } # this calls the mobility method instead of getting the plain attribute, so it will translate on the admin.
    end
  end
end
```

In this case, all the fields will be calling the original method name, instead of the plain attribute. So for example, in my case, it will be calling `ngo.impact_description`, which will get the field translated, instead of reading the plain attribute `ngo[:impact_description]`, which will always be in the default language.